# Signature Creating for txt files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, similarity

I am making a code that is counting all the words in a text file and is supposed to sort the top 25 most occurring words in the text file, which is known as a signature, and then store it in a list. Next, it is supposed to compare the signatures using the Jaccard Similarity Measure. I have the code for Jaccard similarity but I need to modify it for my program since I took it from a different example. The code that is creating the signature is giving me this error:
Column 'Prophet' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nlargest' with this type

```
I was doing research on ways to how I can sort all the words by the top 25 most common ones and this is the most efficient way but it's giving me this error. Is there another way that I can sort this out? Also, how would I then add the 25 words into a new list for each text? Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Please show the change in code. Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: What is column "Prophet" supposed to be?  What this is saying is that you're trying to do a numerical operation on a column that does not consist of numbers.

Comment: We cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: The first part of the question reminds me of the computer sciencist who, over several days, produced a beautifully documented and tested program to count word occurrences in text files. And the other computer scientist who did the same thing with a four-line shell script ;)

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you for your comment, I understand now. The column Prophet is just a column that was made for one of the txt files. Prophet is the name of one of the txt files, should have clarified

Comment: @JackDeeth sorry i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of error:

`nlargest` cannot act on `object` column such as a string column, and because in your `df` there is at least one column (except for `"Word"`) that is an `object` column, so it raised the error at that column.

Fix of error:

`print(df.dtypes)` to inspect the data type of each column, and either not to apply `nlargest` on `object` column, or convert `object` column to other type (such as `int`, `float`).

> how I can sort all the words by the top 25 most common ones and this is the most efficient way ... Is there another way that I can sort this out?

I think `nlargest` should be your choice, just make sure the column that you are applying `nlargest` is **the number of counts of the corresponding word**. Also, if you have such column, you don't actually need to use a loop to iterate over all columns, because you only need to do `nlargest` on that particular column.

> Also, how would I then add the 25 words into a new list for each text?

Refers to this example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Word': ['happy', 'hello', 'you', 'he', 'she', 'it'],
    'Count': [27, 32,19, 6,80, 5]
})

largest = df.set_index('Word')['Count'].nlargest(3)
print(largest)
```

Output:

```
Word
she      80
hello    32
happy    27
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

You will get a `pd.Series` of the (3) largest counts, and the corresponding word as the index. Then you can extract the index and convert it into a list by

```
largest.index.tolist()
```

Lastly, if your dataframe has a different column format from my example above, it would be better for you to convert yours into mine. If you are not sure how to convert, you need to share a subdataframe here for us to look at. You can export the first 10 rows of your dataframe by `print(df.head(10).to_dict('list'))` and paste the outcome as text in your question.